# How to detect run-time stack smashing/buffer overflow in C and enable gdb to exit gracefully with proper message.?

Tags: c, multithreading, gdb, buffer-overflow, stack-smash

Buffer overflow is causing gdb to behave in a erratic way and proper logs are not being printed. How to enable gdb to print logs in a proper way?

Also, is there a way to detect runtime stack smashing in a multithreaded environment?

Searched about `-lmcheck` but it is not thread safe.

Comment: How about tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `gcc` you may try option `-fstack-overflow` combined with the `valgrind` tools.